# How to display arraybuffer video stream data with out using Media Source Extensions?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

We are working on  video player. We area receiving video  stream  through web sockets as a arraybuffer. We can able to play video by using MSE. But we had  a probelm in  IOS browsers which  they dont support MSE and we dont want to use HLS. Any other way we can play video using arraybuffer data with out unsing MSE?

Comment: Check this related question, could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045857/live-video-streaming-with-html-5

Comment: This wont Help. Thank you